# Uninstall F# from VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-2015

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2015 (Enterprise), and although I only selected C++ from the programming languages list, it has also installed F#. A language I have never used and will not use, simply because I'm working with C# and VB currently, and I'm satisfied with the results I get. My plan is moving to C++ after I learn C#, so I have nothing to do with F#. It's only taking up space from my disk and I want to remove it. I've been looking all morning about an easy way to do so, but all I could find was a lot of questions regarding earlier VS releases and somehow managed to successfully remove the F# project templates. But the rest is still there - screenshot:
[image: Cannot Uninstall]

As you can see I cannot uninstall it via Extensions and Updates, nor I can find it in Programs and Features. I could find some F# SDK and F# for VS stuff in the registry, but I'm not experienced enough with it to find the uninstallers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto Programs and Features in Windows, and select Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 and click Change, when the Setup dialog appears, select Modify then untick the following:

[image]

Comment: I already tried that and I had it unchecked when I clicked Modify. It won't let me click on Update.

Comment: @JohnyP. It's fate telling you to try F#, despite you thinking you don't want to. Go on, you'll love it! ;)

Comment: @DavidArno Well... might as well leave it be. For now.